# Labelling outliers in ggBoxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to annotate the outliers in a multi-group box-plot generated from the dataframe below:

`Chr. variable value
1      1      W01 21270
2      2      W01 15478
3      3      W01 12479
4      4      W01  9293
5      5      W01  9936
6      6      W01 13160
7      7      W01 10386
8      8      W01  8021
9      9      W01  9627
10    10      W01  9635
11    11      W01 12918
12    12      W01 11617
13    13      W01  4158
14    14      W01  6863
15    15      W01  7259
16    16      W01 10021
17    17      W01 12567
18    18      W01  3752
19    19      W01 15910
20    20      W01  5557
21    21      W01  2908
22    22      W01  5247
23     X      W01  4052
24     Y      W01    42
25     1      W02 24278
26     2      W02 17624
27     3      W02 14105
.      .      .
.      .      .`

I adopted the following solution from [this thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524669/labeling-outliers-of-boxplots-in-r)

`is_outlier <- function(x) {
  return(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x))
}`

`dat.m %>% group_by(Chr.) %>% mutate(outlier = ifelse(is_outlier(value), value, as.numeric(NA))) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = factor(Chr.), y = value)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_text(aes(label = outlier), na.rm = TRUE, hjust = -0.3)`

[image]

This however does not work for some reason. I'd like to label outliers with the corresponding value in the `variable` column. Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think I understand your example code.  Should it work with your example dataset or the data in the linked question?  Your variable is called `value` (I think), not `drat`.  And you're missing the code that makes the text variable as a string, which is what the labels are based on in the linked answer.  Can you add more of your code so we can see it (and maybe an example dataset that has an outlier in it :-) )?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestion. I edited accordingly!

Comment: I don't understand. Your plot has what you asked: outliers labeled with their value. Can you be more specific to what is wrong in your opinion?

Comment: Oh, great, I think I see now.  That answer you're working with makes the labels in two steps: first they make a logical variable `is_outlier` and then they make the label from that.  You could do this in one step in your `mutate()` call.  Like `mutate(outlier = ifelse(is_outlier(value), as.character(variable), NA))`.  Notice I use `variable` for the labels instead of `value`.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks a lot for your help. It resolves the problem. Could you please also post it as the Answer so I could mark this thread as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are making the labeling variable `outlier` out of `value` instead of out of `variable`.

In order to use `variable` as the label you'll want to change the code within `mutate()` to something like

```
mutate(outlier = ifelse(is_outlier(value), as.character(variable), NA) )
```

The `as.character()` part of the code has to do with working with factors.  If `variable` is already a character instead of a factor you won't need it.