# Labeling Outliers of Boxplots in a loop R

Tags: r

I have been trying to change the code from the ['labeling outliers in a boxplot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524669/labeling-outliers-of-boxplots-in-r) to get it to work in a loop (of columns in a df).

```
ens_id=names(mtcars)
for(i in 1:length(ens_id)){
 
 dat <- test %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(var="outlier") %>% group_by(cond) %>% mutate(is_outlier=ifelse(is_outlier(as.numeric(ens_id[i])),as.numeric(ens_id[i]), as.numeric(NA)))
 dat$outlier[which(is.na(dat$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)
 
 p=ggplot(dat, aes_string(y=ens_id[i], x="cond",fill="cond")) + geom_boxplot()  + ylab(gene_id[i])+ geom_text(aes(label=outlier),na.rm=TRUE,nudge_x=0.15)
 ggsave(p, file=paste0("/media/chi/Figures/HVOLvsCDCS/",ens_id[i],".png"), width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm")
 }
```

> Error in quantile.default(x, 0.25) :    missing values and NaN's not
> allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE In addition: Warning message: In
> is_outlier(as.numeric(ens_id[i])) : NAs introduced by coercion

I used as.numeric(ens_id[i])  to get around the error:

> Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: sorry @akrun, you beat me to it - I was just about to try to edit my post

Comment: yes, it should be the df mtcars

Comment: Thanks, one doubt is that you are grouping by 'cond' and should that be removed from the `ens_id`

Comment: I think I understand why you are getting that issue.  The `outlier` column was not updated.  `dat$outlier[which(is.na(dat$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)`. There are two columns `is_outlier` and `outlier`.  Please check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the strings i.e. the column names as strings are not evaluated.  An option is to pass the strings  directly in `across` or convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`). As the former is more easier, here we show that

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(stringr)
for(i in seq_along(ens_id)) {

      dat <-  test %>%
          tibble::rownames_to_column(var="outlier") %>%
          group_by(cond) %>%
          mutate(across(ens_id[i], ~ replace(., !is_outlier(.), NA), .names = "{col}_is_outlier")) %>%
          # or use mutate_at (if the version is less than 1.0.0
          #mutate_at(vars(ens_id[i]), list(is_outlier = ~replace(., !is_outlier(.), NA))) %>%
          rename_at(vars(ends_with('is_outlier')), ~ str_remove(., str_c(ens_id[i], "_")))
     
      dat$outlier[which(is.na(dat$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)
      print(head(dat))

   }
```

---

Or as mentioned above, the second option is to evaluate (`!!`) after converting to `sym`bol

```
for(i in seq_along(ens_id)) {
      dat <- test %>%
               tibble::rownames_to_column(var="outlier") %>%
               group_by(cond) %>%
               mutate(is_outlier = replace(!! sym(ens_id[i]), 
                     !is_outlier(!!sym(ens_id[i])), NA)) 
       dat$outlier[which(is.na(dat$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)
       print(head(dat))
   }
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
ens_id <- c("mpg", "wt")
 test <- mtcars
 test$mpg[10] <- 9800
 test$wt[22] <- 4895
 plist <- vector('list', length(ens_id))
 for(i in seq_along(ens_id)) {

       dat <-  test %>%
           tibble::rownames_to_column(var="outlier") %>%
           group_by(gear) %>%
           mutate(across(ens_id[i], ~ replace(., !is_outlier(.), NA), .names = "{col}_is_outlier")) %>%
           # or use mutate_at (if the version is less than 1.0.0
           #mutate_at(vars(ens_id[i]), list(is_outlier = ~replace(., !is_outlier(.), NA))) %>%
           rename_at(vars(ends_with('is_outlier')), ~ str_remove(., str_c(ens_id[i], "_")))
     
       dat$outlier[which(is.na(dat$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)
       plist[[i]] <- ggplot(dat, aes_string(y=ens_id[i], x="gear", group="gear")) +
                geom_boxplot()  +
                 ylab(ens_id[i])+ 
                 geom_text(aes(label=outlier), na.rm=TRUE, nudge_x=0.15)

    }
    
plist[[1]]
plist[[2]]
```

Comment: @zoe I used `dplyr 1.0.0`. If you have a version less than 1.0.0, use `mutate_at(vars(ens_id[i]), ~ replace(., !is_outlier(.), NA))`

Comment: dat isn't getting a new column of dat$outlier? The column of the values to plot in the boxplot is being replaced with 'NA' or the value of the outlier so it doesn't plot as desired. Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'is_outlier'.

Comment: @zoe It is from `library(stringr)`. I did updated that in the code

Comment: thankyou so much. It is now working but it is plotting all of the sample names and not just the outliers? I used:   ggplot(dat, aes_string(y=ens_id[i], x="cond",fill="cond")) + geom_boxplot()  + ylab(gene_id[i])+ geom_text(aes(label=outlier),na.rm=TRUE,nudge_x=0.15)

Comment: I need the full data set to plot the boxplots??

Comment: @zoe I added with a reproducible example.